# Javascript radio button value won't parse to PHP hidden field

Tags: javascript, php

I can display the selected value (0 or 1 with input type="text") but it won't parse the value to my hidden field to be saved in my database (using input type="hidden" to mysql column 'palletised'), no idea what I'm missing here?

```
   <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <?= FORM::label('category', __('Are the Goods/Items Palletised?'), array('for'=>'category'))?>      
            <input type="radio" name="radiogroup" class="radiogroup" value="0" />No
            <input type="radio" name="radiogroup" class="radiogroup" value="1" />Yes
            <br /><br />
            <input type="text" name="amount" id="amount" /> 
            <input type="hidden" id="palletised" name="amount"/></input>
        </div>      
    </div>

<script>
$('.radiogroup').on('change', function() {
  $('#amount').val( this.value );
});
</script>
```

Comment: your hidden input id is #palletised so  $('#palletised').val( this.value );

Comment: If you want to copy the value to a hidden input, you need to add code to copy that value to said input... I mean, you're already setting the value to the non-hidden input.

Comment: name attribute should be unique name="amount"

Comment: ` <input type="text" name="amount" id="amount" />` 
    `<input type="hidden" id="palletised" name="amount"/>`
name must be unique. both name are amount.

Comment: @JYoThI: not true. The `name` attribute is not required to be unique. Otherwise, `document.getElementsByName` wouldn't return a set.

Comment: @Bhaskar: See ^

Comment: Thanks Bhaskar that did the trick nicely. It's because I was using the value already with the input text... Silly me ;-)

Comment: @FusionDesign: Your problem is ___not___ in the name attribute. After this line: `$('#amount').val( this.value);`, just _add_ `$('#palletised').val( this.value);`

Comment: is it possible to access two same name element in php unless name="amount[]"

Comment: @JYoThI Yes it is possible, although you have to manually parse it from the raw postData (check [php://input](http://php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php.php#wrappers.php.input)). But the information is there and can be accessed. That's the reason that `amount[]` can work in the first place in PHP. HTML forms don't differ wether the name is `amount` or `amount[]`, it's all handled the same way; all entries are serialized and sent to the server. Only the backend differs on how to parse these two.

Comment: thank you for the info @Thomas

Comment: @JYoThI great piece of information, good to know...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check this code. first assign value in amount text and then hidden field but one thing do not use same input same

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-md-8">
        <input type="radio" name="radiogroup" class="radiogroup" value="0"/>No
        <input type="radio" name="radiogroup" class="radiogroup" value="1"/>Yes
        <br/><br/>
        <input type="text" name="amount" id="amount"/>
        <input type="hidden" id="palletised" name="amount_value" /></input>
    </div>
</div>

<script>
    $('.radiogroup').on('change', function () {
        $('#amount').val(this.value);
        $('#palletised').val(this.value);
    });
</script>
```

Comment: The `name` attribute is not required to be unique.

Comment: update my code, i used for specific

Comment: Yes! that's where I went wrong, the value should be unique...

Comment: if you unique then check my update answer

Answer (score -1):

```
$('.radiogroup').on('change', function() {
  $('#palletised').val( this.value );
});
```

because # is the id selector